# How to check if ModelState contains errors which are not properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, error-handling, modelstate

In View i have following error helper

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Which, if some property is not validated, show following html

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors">
<ul>
<li style="display:none"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have custom css for this class with red border background and problem is that even no error text is shown to user, red border is still displayed.

Can i somehow prevent showing following error html ? Like

```
@if (Html.ModelState.ContainsNonPropertyErrors() == true)
{
Html.ValidationSummary(true)
}
```

// or to check if ModelState Error array contains empty keys, becase these are custom messages.

also, can i somehow check if form was submitted to display successfull message ?

for example

```
@if (Html.ModelState.FormWasSubmitted() == true)
    {
    if (Html.ModelState.ContainsNonPropertyErrors() == true)
    {
    Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    } else {
    Html.Raw("Operation was successfull.")
    }
}
```

or it is a good practice to have model.successfullMessage property in the ViewModel ? (and in view something like `@if(ModelState.IsValid) {@Model.successfullMessage}` )

How do you do it ?

Comment: Just style the `<ul>` element - `.validation-summary-errors > ul { border: ... }`

Comment: aah so simple as always :-) Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i think i have working solution

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.Keys.Contains(string.Empty))
{
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
}
```